# Firemonkey does not show Hebrew text in iOS

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey, hebrew

When I fill in a FMX control (like TLabel, TText or TMemo) with a Hebrew text - it's not being shown in iOS (in Android and Win it works fine), only punctuation appears and non-Hebrew symbols. Even in a blank project with just one label on a clean form.

Is not it supported or did I forget to configure my project with some encoding/codepage etc.?

```
Delphi 10.3 Version 26.0.36039.7899;
iPhone 7 Plus, iOS 13.5.1;
Mac OS Catalina 10.15.4
```

Comment: Did you try to set "Controltype" to "Platform"? - then it should use native iOS controls instead and I suppose it will work with Hebrew.

Comment: Yes, I tried and it doesn't work for me cause it destroys any styles used. Moreover it "fixes" not all of the FMX components (e.g. it helped with TListView and didn't with TLabel)

Answer (score 1):

These are mostly software bugs .Persian, Arabic and Hebrew languages in FireMonkey aren't well supported. I suggest using the following free components. According to the site's information, the Hebrew language problem has been solved.

Download Link:
http://www.fmxrtl.com/

Comment: Yes, I know this solution. It really works in most cases (at least in a clean project it helped), but I can't integrate it into my main project due to Alcinoe components already used there. Since Alcinoe asks to patch some of standard FMX units and FmxRTL is precompiled - I can't run them together due to [DCC Fatal Error] Main.pas(19): F2051 Unit RTL.ComboEdit.Style was compiled with a different version of FMX.Layouts.TScrollBox.Paint